# No command is working in VMWare with Linux

Tags: terminal

Is there a way to install apt-get onto Linux? It seems that no command works whenever I attempt to install nmap or do anything for that matter.
I tried several commands and watched multiple videos with no luck.
I've attached a picture of my error.[image]

Comment: Have you checked to see that your `PATH` is set with `echo $PATH` as root or the actual user? Do other commands such as `ls` and `cd` work?

Comment: For the command echo $PATH, I get this: /sbin:bin/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/games:/opt/bin:

Comment: ls only shows me what I downloaded. which includes my nmap-7.70-1.x86_64(2).rpm and cd doesn't show anything

Comment: Your path looks fine to me and `ls` is working. What distro of Linux are you using? `yum` and `apt-get` aren't going to be on the same system by default as the former is for installing and updating packages for Fedora/RHEL/CentOS and the latter is for Debian/Ubuntu/Mint. `cd` is just to change directories. If you use it by itself, it'll just move you to your home. If you do `cd /var/log` then does it move you into that directory?

Comment: It says Linux box 2.4.31. It moves me into the directory, yes

Comment: Not, the kernel, but the distro. `cat /etc/*-release` will give you that info. That kernel is very old so your distro is also very old and most likely EOL.

Comment: I typed it in, it just says: no such file or directory for the cat /etc/*-release

Comment: What does `lsb_release -a` or `cat /proc/version` give you?

Comment: lsb_release -a gives me: command not found and cat /proc/version says: Linux version 2.4.31 (root@box) (gcc version 2.95.4 20011002 (Debian prerelease) #6 SMP Fri Oct 21 15:15:54 EDT 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add `apt-get` (or any of the `apt` family) to the Linux distribution you've installed here.

Perhaps you should choose something other than Damm Small Linux if there are particular packages you want to install. Or look in DSLPanel to see what you can install.

Comment: It's better he uses something other than a distro which hasn't had a release since 2012. If he wants to use `apt` then it's better he use Debian, Ubuntu, or Mint which are all good for beginner.